# How can I remove seo_pro cache

Tags: php, content-management-system, opencart2.x

I try to remove the `seo_pro` cache file with `$this->cache->delete('seo_pro')` during some CRUD operations in admin page. But it doesn't work.

Example:

```
public function addCategory($data) {
        $this->event->trigger('pre.admin.category.add', $data);

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "category SET parent_id = '" . (int)$data['parent_id'] . "', `top` = '" . (isset($data['top']) ? (int)$data['top'] : 0) . "', `column` = '" . (int)$data['column'] . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$data['sort_order'] . "', status = '" . (int)$data['status'] . "', date_modified = NOW(), date_added = NOW()");

        $category_id = $this->db->getLastId();

        if (isset($data['image'])) {
            $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "category SET image = '" . $this->db->escape($data['image']) . "' WHERE category_id = '" . (int)$category_id . "'");
        }

        foreach ($data['category_description'] as $language_id => $value) {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description SET category_id = '" . (int)$category_id . "', language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "', name = '" . $this->db->escape($value['name']) . "', description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['description']) . "', meta_title = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_title']) . "', meta_h1 = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_h1']) . "', meta_description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_description']) . "', meta_keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_keyword']) . "'");
        }

        // MySQL Hierarchical Data Closure Table Pattern
        $level = 0;

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "category_path` WHERE category_id = '" . (int)$data['parent_id'] . "' ORDER BY `level` ASC");

        foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `" . DB_PREFIX . "category_path` SET `category_id` = '" . (int)$category_id . "', `path_id` = '" . (int)$result['path_id'] . "', `level` = '" . (int)$level . "'");

            $level++;
        }

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `" . DB_PREFIX . "category_path` SET `category_id` = '" . (int)$category_id . "', `path_id` = '" . (int)$category_id . "', `level` = '" . (int)$level . "'");

        if (isset($data['category_filter'])) {
            foreach ($data['category_filter'] as $filter_id) {
                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "category_filter SET category_id = '" . (int)$category_id . "', filter_id = '" . (int)$filter_id . "'");
            }
        }

        if (isset($data['category_store'])) {
            foreach ($data['category_store'] as $store_id) {
                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "category_to_store SET category_id = '" . (int)$category_id . "', store_id = '" . (int)$store_id . "'");
            }
        }

        // Set which layout to use with this category
        if (isset($data['category_layout'])) {
            foreach ($data['category_layout'] as $store_id => $layout_id) {
                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "category_to_layout SET category_id = '" . (int)$category_id . "', store_id = '" . (int)$store_id . "', layout_id = '" . (int)$layout_id . "'");
            }
        }

        if (isset($data['keyword'])) {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias SET query = 'category_id=" . (int)$category_id . "', keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($data['keyword']) . "'");
        }

        $this->cache->delete('seo_pro');
        $this->cache->delete('category');

        $this->event->trigger('post.admin.category.add', $category_id);

        return $category_id;
    }
```

One interesting thing - `$this->cache->delete('category')` works perfectly.

Comment: I don't know anything about the tools you use, but is all that code relevant to the question? Always try to post an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my long silence. I solved that issue by removing the same files in **system/storage/modification** folder.